# finding first key-value pair in a hash with value with Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash.

```
        '20111124' => undef,
        '20111125' => undef,
        '20111129' => undef,
        '20111130' => '126002',
        '20111201' => '126002',
        '20111202' => '126002',
        '20111205' => '126002',
        '20111206' => '126002',
        '20111207' => '126002'
```

I'd like to get the first key that has a value.

I have tried iterating the hash but since the hash is sometimes large, what is the fastest way possible to get the first key that does have a defined value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
my ($result) = grep {defined $hash{$_}} sort keys %hash;
```

Comment: This will filter out keys that have defined value which is logically false (ie. numeric 0, empty string etc.)

Comment: This does the trick. the values is just either undefined or defined.

Comment: `List::Util::first` would be better than `grep`, because it stops after finding first match, whereas `grep` creates list of matching keys and discards all but the first one.

Comment: That depends on defined/undefined ratio in the hash. If undefs are a small percentage of values, you're right. If, however, there are many undefs, it is better to first filter them out, and sort only the remaining keys to reduce time (my answer below does that).

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as "first key" in hash, as hashes are not ordered. If I understand your problem correctly, you want the key that is lexicographically lowest. The best solution is probably first filter out the keys that have undef as value, then sort the remaining. This is a costly operation, but I see no easy way around it. Assuming your hash is named %h, this code does the trick:

```
my @sorted_keys = sort(grep(defined($h{$_}), keys(%h)))
my $first_key = $sorted_keys[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since speed is the primary concern, it is wasteful to do a `sort` at all: it orders the entire list, when all that is wanted is the minimum value. It will be far faster to call `minstr` from `List::Util` which does just a single pass of the values: the first iteration of a bubble sort, if you like.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use List::Util 'minstr';

my %dates = (
    '20111124' => undef,
    '20111125' => undef,
    '20111129' => undef,
    '20111130' => '126002',
    '20111201' => '126002',
    '20111202' => '126002',
    '20111205' => '126002',
    '20111206' => '126002',
    '20111207' => '126002',
);

my $first = minstr grep { defined $dates{$_} } keys %dates;

say $first;
```

#### output

```
20111130
```

You can also do this with a single pass of the hash in Perl

```
my $first;
for my $date ( keys %dates ) {
    if ( defined $dates{$date} ) {
        $first = $date unless defined $first and $first le $date;
    }
}
```

There's a slim chance that this may be faster as it doesn't involve creating the intermediate list of keys that have defined values, but there is a lot of Perl code here whereas `minstr` and `grep` are calls to C code. I'm not in a position to benchmark the two at present; perhaps someone else would like the exercise?